# Web form is submitting blank data to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to send data from a web form to my database using PHP. The user enters their `full_name`,`contact_number` and `best_time_to_call` details in the text boxes. When the boxes are filled with the relevant information and hit submit, the data is added to the database perfectly fine only that the columns are blank. How could i resolve this issue?

**HTML**

```
 <form name="frmContact" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" id="frmCallContact" method="POST">
    enter code here<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" class="TableFormat">
        <tr>
         <th align="left" valign="top" colspan="2">Call me back</td>
       </tr>         
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">Full Name:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="FullName" id="FullName_R" style="width:250px;" title="Please enter your full name"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">Contact Number:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="ContactNumber" id="ContactNumber_R" style="width:250px;" /></td>
       </tr>
     <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">Best Time to Call:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="BestTime" id="BestTime_R" style="width:250px;"  title="Please enter your best time to call"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
         <td><!--<a name="submit" href="#"><img src="/img/bn_submit.png" width="93" height="28" /></a>--><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
       </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/bootstrap.php');
    include("config/cn.php");
    $template['template']="page";

    if($_POST){


    // Data pulled from input form
    $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
    $contact_number = $_POST['contact_number'];
    $best_time_to_call = $_POST['best_time_to_call'];


    $enter_sql = "INSERT INTO contact (full_name,contact_number,best_time_to_call) VALUES('$full_name','$contact_number','$best_time_to_call')";
    /*print($enter_sql);*/

    $enter_query = mysql_query($enter_sql) or die(mysql_error());

    header('Location: /thankyou.php');
    exit;
} 

?>
```

Comment: Your form has the following: 'name="FullName"' and in your PHP code you use: 'full_name'. Use print_r($_POST); to see what you get.

Comment: What do you mean by " data is added to the database perfectly fine only that the columns are blank"? If data is added perfectly, columns shouldn't be blank right?

Comment: @SandeepNayak what i mean is that the connection is fine so i am able to submit data to my database

Comment: @Pakspul Thank you. I didn't realise that they did not match.

Comment: Same mistake as noted by @Pakspul with other fields also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/bootstrap.php');
    include("config/cn.php");
    $template['template']="page";

    if($_POST){


    // Data pulled from input form
    $full_name = $_POST['FullName'];
    $contact_number = $_POST['ContactNumber'];
    $best_time_to_call = $_POST['BestTime'];


    $enter_sql = "INSERT INTO contact (full_name,contact_number,best_time_to_call) VALUES('$full_name','$contact_number','$best_time_to_call')";
    /*print($enter_sql);*/

    $enter_query = mysql_query($enter_sql) or die(mysql_error());

    header('Location: /thankyou.php');
    exit;
} 

?>
```